# Leetcode 125 Why fail

Tags: string

My code is as below:
When the input is
"A man, a plan, a canal: Panama", I got false, which is wrong. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        String fixedS = "";
        
        for(char a: s.toCharArray()){
            if(Character.isLetter(a) || Character.isDigit(a)){
                fixedS += a;
            }
        fixedS = fixedS.toLowerCase();
            
        int start = 0;
        int end = fixedS.length()-1;
            
        while(start <= end){
            if(fixedS.charAt(start) != fixedS.charAt(end)){
                return false;
            }
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        }return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to put a few `print` statements and debug what's happening vs. expected?

Comment: Thank you so much. I find the error, it's the wrong place of the braces that cause this error